# Can I rent a car in Paris without a credit card?

Tags: car-rentals, payment-cards

I want to rent a car for 2 days in Paris but I only hold a debit card (VISA).
Is it possible to rent it without a credit card?

If so, can anybody tell me what car rental company accepts debit card at pickup time?
I heard there are some smaller companies that do that, but I can't seem to find one of it.

Comment: If it's a VISA debit cart, then it can be used as a credit card anywhere VISA is accepted, so you shouldn't have to worry about it.  The only concern is if the rental company puts a temporary charge on your account for some sort of deposit - you won't be able to use that money until the hold drops off (usually about a week).  On a separate note, do think hard whether you really need a car in Paris, especially if you haven't driven there before.

Comment: But can't they check to see what kind of card type it is? And what kind of amount are they charging? Like 300 euros?

Comment: @Bogdan probably this kind of amount, yes.

Comment: @BogdanPopa I am adding the info I stated as an answer - with a bit of further explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a VISA debit cart, then it can be used as a credit card anywhere VISA is accepted, so you shouldn't have to worry about it.

Note that many rental companies will want to charge the deposit to the card - most likely in the area of €200-300.  This money will be unavailable to you if the charge is on the debit card.

While it's easy to determine whether the card is a debit or credit card (often, but not always) by the card number alone, the rental company won't care.  All they need is to be able to charge the amount owed to them.

On a separate note, I strongly advise that you think carefully whether you really need a car in Paris.  Paris is one of the worst cities in Europe to drive in.

**Updated based on the comment:**
If you want to rent the car to go to Belgium, you may need to inform the rental company that you will be taking the car out of the country - which in turn may make the cost of rental more expensive.  You will likely be breaking the terms of your rental contract if you take the car across the country border without notifying the rental company.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I agree you don't need a car in Paris since you have all sorts of public transport solutions. I want to rent it to go to Belgium for the weekend, since by train is more expensive.

Comment: @BogdanPopa Please note my update to the answer.

Comment: Quickly: the Visa cards acceptance may be true in France, it is not everywhere. In the US for example, a credit card is specifically asked (to check credit history).

Comment: @Vince I disagree.  I have rented cars in the USA without a credit card, using MasterCard debit card (in Chicago) and even paying cash and not using a card at all (in Boston).  I had to leave a $200 cash deposit when paying with cash.  And this cash thing was a good 15 years ago.

Comment: @AleksG OK you're probably right, I have never done it myself but I heard it depends on the company and the country of issue of your card. Did you have a US debit card and did you go to Avis/Hertz or the cheaper Alamo/Enterprise? I think that is the difference, even though it is just what I heard.

Comment: @Vince yes, it was a US issued card, but I wouldn't remember now which company it was.  It may also be worth noting that in Europe a lot more people only have debit cards (and not credit cards) than in the USA.

Comment: My wife (French citizen, US resident) has a US VISA Debit card and this was rejected to rent a car in both El Paso, Texas, USA and Monterey, California, USA.  However, her *French* VISA Debit card was accepted at the same locations.

Comment: I have definitely had the experience of not being able to hire a car in France with only a debit card, so I  don't think you should just rely on it all being fine. It was Alamo/National at Grenoble Airport in 2007, with a UK visa debit card if that makes a difference. I booked over the internet using the same card, but apparently you needed an actual credit not debit card to collect the car. (Someone else I was travelling with had a credit card, which solved our problem.)

Comment: But what happens if I'm the only driver and I'm not being able to hire it with the debit card? There will some sort of reserveration cancelation fees?

Comment: @BogdanPopa Why not call the hire company and ask?

Comment: @AleksG because when I called, even if their terms and conditions stated that you can use a debit card at rental time, on the phone they are saying it is not possible. So I thought it was a necessary step in order to ask the next question.